# How to draw a path(or polyline, route) in augmented reality

Tags: javascript, coordinates, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am trying to create a function that guides the way on the screen using AR.js.

In the official reference documentation, there are instructions on how to show images in GPS coordinates, but I'm not sure how to draw shapes or lines between coordinates and coordinates.
What can I do to show the line that a person must follow to get to a specific destination, like the image below?

[image]

The image above is a screen using the ARCL library to develop iOS augmented reality applications in the Swift language. I want to implement the above screen using AR.js.

I would appreciate if you let me know how.
Thank you.